# Spacing out floating elements with both sides of a container

Tags: css, css-float

I have floating elements that are laid out basically as a grid and I want to make them flush with both the left and right sides of the container while retaining internal separation.

Here's an example where the red squares are floating 50x50  divs with 10 pixels of separation inside a blue div with a fixed width and auto-height.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln8jf.png

[image]

```
<div class='blue' style='width: 110px'>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
</div>

<div class='blue' style='width: 110px'>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
</div>

<div class='blue' style='width: 170px'>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='red'></div>
</div>
```

Here's a relevant fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sujadkvb/5/

I want to make the red squares completely flush with the left and right sides of the blue square.  The blue square can be of several widths and red squares can be added or hidden so an nth-of-type selector that modifies the margins on specific red squares isn't practical.

This could be solved by giving the blue squares a negative right-padding but the CSS spec disallows negative padding for some unspecified reason so now I'm stuck.  I don't see how anyone can justify allowing negative margins but disallowing negative padding.

Comment: would u please add an extra image, regarding your desired output?

Comment: Desired output image is linked in the question and the fiddle.  Stackoverflow wouldn't let me include it inline.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ln8jf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of realizing your layout using inline-blocks instead of floated elements.

First, to the `.blue` containing block, set the following CSS properties: `text-align: justify` and `line-height: 0`.

Second, for the `.red` child elements, remove the `float` property and add `display: inline-block`.

The result is that your `.red` elements are now inline and will be spaced evenly in a line within the width of the `.blue` container.  Since you hard-coded a nice value of the width for `.blue`, you will get the horizontal spacing that you want between the `.red` blocks (no need to set a right margin).

The remaining issue with `text-align: justify` is that the final line will not stretch to fill the full width (this is how the justify setting works in order to prevent short lines from being stretched out in a ugly fashion).

To work around this, add a pseudo-element `.blue:after` which is an inline-block of width 100%.  This will force a new line to be created after your red blocks, and the result is that all the red blocks are left/right justified.

The `line-height: 0` on `.blue` and `vertical-align: top` on `.blue:after` take care of any extra white space at the bottom due to line leading (space above and below the baseline of the text).

```css
.blue {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #00A2E8;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
}
.blue:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='blue' style='width: 110px'>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
</div>
<div class='blue' style='width: 110px'>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
</div>
<div class='blue' style='width: 170px'>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
  <div class='red'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat solution!  I would not have thought of that.  Great job.